# How to get a variable which can be viewed from console

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm coding an extension which downloads a file, before downloading the file, I need to get a token which is already generated from the website on loading.
This token can be viewed from the console by typing >GetPublicTokenResult

How can I read this variable into my content script?

I've tried the following:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(["GetPublicTokenResult"], function(items){ items = [ { "yourBody": "myBody" } ]
console.log(items);
});
```

but it seems that this variable is not stored in Storage, but it can be viewed in Memory snap

Comment: You need a ["page script" to access page variables](/a/9517879) + [another example](/a/46870005).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content scripts run in an isolated environment from the page. They can only interact with the DOM,  javascript code can't be accesed. You need to inject your code *directly* in the page. Check out [Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/insert-code-into-the-page-context-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879) for a detailed tutorial.